# Why is my firebase realtime database data reseting each time I open the app?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to upload some data to my firebase realtime database, but everytime I start the app, the data resets and my database is empty. Why is this?

This is all done within a fragment.

I've also created a POJO Months class and a MonthList class for the listView/

Below is all of the code concerning firebase.

```
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    EditText editText;

    public void addMonth(){

        String id = databaseReference.getKey();

        String name = editText.getText().toString();
        boolean ifPaid = true;

        Months months = new Months(name, id, ifPaid);
        databaseReference.push().setValue(months);

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do,container,false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        final ListView listView = v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("month");

        editText = v.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        monthsList = new ArrayList<>();

        //button that triggers addMonth() method.

        Button upload = v.findViewById(R.id.upload);

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addMonth();
            }
        });

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                monthsList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot monthsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Months months = monthsSnapshot.getValue(Months.class);

                    monthsList.add(months);

                }

                MonthList adapter = new MonthList(getActivity(), monthsList);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you shared that should be deleting data from the database. Can you show what the database looks like before you (re)run the app, and after it? Preferably by adding the JSON from the database to your question (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Sorry, realised I left a line that I didn't notice that did all of this. :D my bad, thanks for the help anyway!